# clean missing values spark with aggregation function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I would like to clean missing values by replacing them by the mean.This source code used to work i do not why , it doesn't work now.Any help will be appreciated.
Here is the dataset i use

```
RowNumber,Poids,Age,Taille,0MI,Hmean,CoocParam,LdpParam,Test2,Classe
0,,72,160,5,,2.9421,,3,4
1,54,70,,5,0.6301,2.7273,,3,
2,,51,164,5,,2.9834,,3,4
3,,74,170,5,0.6966,2.9654,2.3699,3,4
4,108,62,,5,0.6087,2.7093,2.1619,3,4
```

Here what i did

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()

    val df = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).format("com.databricks.spark.csv").load("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/data_with_missing_values3.csv")
    df.show(false)
    var newDF = df
    df.dtypes.foreach { x =>
      val colName = x._1
      newDF = newDF.na.fill(df.agg(max(colName)).first()(0).toString, Seq(colName))
    }
    newDF.show(false)
```

Here is the result , nothing happened

```
initial_data

    +---------+-----+---+------+---+------+---------+--------+-----+------+
    |RowNumber|Poids|Age|Taille|0MI|Hmean |CoocParam|LdpParam|Test2|Classe|
    +---------+-----+---+------+---+------+---------+--------+-----+------+
    |0        |null |72 |160   |5  |null  |2.9421   |null    |3    |4     |
    |1        |54   |70 |null  |5  |0.6301|2.7273   |null    |3    |null  |
    |2        |null |51 |164   |5  |null  |2.9834   |null    |3    |4     |
    |3        |null |74 |170   |5  |0.6966|2.9654   |2.3699  |3    |4     |
    |4        |108  |62 |null  |5  |0.6087|2.7093   |2.1619  |3    |4     |
    +---------+-----+---+------+---+------+---------+--------+-----+------+

    new_data
    +---------+-----+---+------+---+------+---------+--------+-----+------+
    |RowNumber|Poids|Age|Taille|0MI|Hmean |CoocParam|LdpParam|Test2|Classe|
    +---------+-----+---+------+---+------+---------+--------+-----+------+
    |0        |null |72 |160   |5  |null  |2.9421   |null    |3    |4     |
    |1        |54   |70 |null  |5  |0.6301|2.7273   |null    |3    |null  |
    |2        |null |51 |164   |5  |null  |2.9834   |null    |3    |4     |
    |3        |null |74 |170   |5  |0.6966|2.9654   |2.3699  |3    |4     |
    |4        |108  |62 |null  |5  |0.6087|2.7093   |2.1619  |3    |4     |
    +---------+-----+---+------+---+------+---------+--------+-----+------+
```

What should i do

Comment: Do you want to replace the null with max value or the mean. You have asked for the mean value and your code example used max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withColumn` api and use `when` function to check for null values in the `columns` as

```
df.dtypes.foreach { x =>
      val colName = x._1
      val fill = df.agg(max(col(s"`$colName`"))).first()(0).toString
      newDF = newDF.withColumn(colName, when(col(s"`$colName`").isNull , fill).otherwise(col(s"`$colName`")) )
    }
    newDF.show(false)
```

I hope this solves your issue

Comment: i got issue when the name of columns contains "." so i need to use s"`${colName}`") ,how can i do it on your solution , am just new Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to replace the `null` values with mean value then you calculate `mean` and `fill` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.mean


val data = spark.read.option("header", true)
      .option("inferSchema", true).format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .load("data.csv")

//Calculate the mean for each column and create a map with its column name 
//and use na.fill() method to replace null with that mean

data.na.fill(data.columns.zip(
      data.select(data.columns.map(mean(_)): _*).first.toSeq
    ).toMap)
```

I have tested the code in local and works fine.

Output:

```
+---------+-----+---+------+---+------------------+---------+------------------+-----+------+
|RowNumber|Poids|Age|Taille|0MI|             Hmean|CoocParam|          LdpParam|Test2|Classe|
+---------+-----+---+------+---+------------------+---------+------------------+-----+------+
|        0|   81| 72|   160|  5|0.6451333333333333|   2.9421|2.2659000000000002|    3|     4|
|        1|   54| 70|   164|  5|            0.6301|   2.7273|2.2659000000000002|    3|     4|
|        2|   81| 51|   164|  5|0.6451333333333333|   2.9834|2.2659000000000002|    3|     4|
|        3|   81| 74|   170|  5|            0.6966|   2.9654|            2.3699|    3|     4|
|        4|  108| 62|   164|  5|            0.6087|   2.7093|            2.1619|    3|     4|
+---------+-----+---+------+---+------------------+---------+------------------+-----+------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks dude , it worked but  when i got "." in columns name i'll.There is an exception caught i need to work with backslash, please any help

Comment: Great to hear that it worked, I thought it was the efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
var imputeDF = df
df.dtypes.foreach { x => 
      val colName = x._1
      newDF = newDF.na.fill(df.agg(max(colName)).first()(0).toString , Seq(colName)) }
```

Note that it is not a good practice to use Mutable data types with scala.

Depending on your data, you can use a SQL join or something else to replace the nulls with a more suitable value.

Comment: please check the update , nothing happened Thanks in advance

Comment: @MaherHTB The columns containing nulls, are they `Int` or `Double` ?